# "No fill" error in Facebook Audience SDK no matter what I do

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

Im trying to impletent native ads, and no matter how minimal my implementation I always get "no fill" error.

I am using my phone. 
I do have native app installed.
I am logged in with the same account that im developer with
I do not have personalised ads tracking turned off

Ive tried making both a hello world fb app with me as admin, and android app, nothing
Ive tried using my "real" facebook account, nothing
Ive tried both wifi and 3g networks, nothing

No requests comming through in the request debugger. I always get no fill error on the device, not even once it server an ad, so I suspect some setup error. I am out of ideas, can you please check it?

fb app id 164610790550461
audience network sdk 4.26.0

Thank you

```
compile ("com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.0", {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.exoplayer"
})

mNativeAdsManager = new NativeAdsManager(getActivity(), "my placement id", 1);
            mNativeAdsManager.setListener(new NativeAdsManager.Listener() {
                public boolean mRetried;

                @Override public void onAdsLoaded() {
                    //
                }

                @Override public void onAdError(AdError adError) {
                    //
                }
            });
            mNativeAdsManager.loadAds();
```

**// EDIT SOLUTION: my phone was blacklisted for some reason, works on other devices ive tested**

Comment: Check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq/#faq_1204719862895859

Comment: Also check Test ads: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing
Moreover "When testing your ad placements, Facebook will intentionally send a no-fill for about 20% of requests to allow you to test how your app or mobile website handles the no-fill case."

Comment: Yes ive read that, but i am logged in and dont have no-track enabled, and I ve never seen a real ad. Other apps that I can see that implement fb ads serve me, so it doesnt make sense that it would have no inventory for me.. any other ideas?

Comment: ive added literally all the fb code i have